# Inverse CircularReveal, circular conceal

Tags: android, animation, kotlin

I am to create a circular conceal, basically the inverse of the [createCircularReveal](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewAnimationUtils.html#createCircularReveal(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float)). However, the circular reveal uses a RevealAnimator which is part of the hidden API in Android, which is to be restricted. Unfortunately also the underlying method that is used, [setRevealClip](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#14977) is also restricted.

So basically with no access to the native functionality how would one go about solving this? Preferable without creating a container view that creates a extra layer of complexity.

Comment: Isn't the reveal is an animation from small radius to bigger one, while conceal is the animation from bigger to small one. Why don't you just change that `radiusFrom` with `radiusTo` values to do conceal?

Comment: @iDemigod That is not the case. For the circularReveal it will show the view from the center out, no matter how you specify `radiusFrom` or `radiusTo`. (If you reverse them you basically reverse the animation). I wish to do the opposite. Make it show from the outside in.

Comment: Did you find and answer to this?

Comment: @ScottCooper Actually not so far.